# return default value form model field

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

In my calculation I have this

`start = Project.objects.all().order_by('created').first().created`,

I'm ordering my projects by `created date` so I can do something with them, now what is the best way to return `default` value from `status`, I need this `value` so I can calculate projects on the date when they are accepted.

`status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ProjectChoices.PROJECT_STATUSES,
default=ProjectChoices.STATUS_STARTED)`

Comment: What do you mean return default? return the status? retrieve a queryset for that enum? other?

Comment: Provide your models, and views.

Comment: @Sayse how to return `default=ProjectChoices.STATUS_STARTED`

Comment: @Sayse and I'll be also eager to know how can I return `choice` from this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return just the results with default status, you can do this:

```
start = Project.objects.filter(status=ProjectChoices.STATUS_STARTED).order_by('created').first().created
```

And you can get the name of choices from `get_FOO_display()` method, try this:

```
start.get_status_display()
```